# unobtrusive-ajax form reloads entire page in updated div net core

Tags: ajax, forms, asp.net-core

Hello I use this form so to pass some parameters to my controller and then to reload data and displayed them in my view.

```
<form method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" ajax-data-records="records" data-ajax-update="#panel" data-ajax-mode='replace' data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        
            <select id="Records" name="records" class="form-control col-lg-12">

                <option value="0" selected>--Choose---</option>
                <option value="1">All Records</option>
                <option value="2">Per User</option>
            </select>

    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>

<div id="panel">

@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      @item.requestID
    }

</div>
```

The problem is that it reloads entire page in my div "panel" including the form. Any idea how can reload only updated view in the div?

thank you

Comment: your `home/index` returns your whole home page, so of course that's what replaces the whole #panel (as controlled by the `data-ajax-mode='replace'`). You need to return the result (looks like a list of items here) that already renders the items into HTML (some kind of partial view). There is no magic here, it's just clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that it reloads entire page in my div "panel" including the form. Any idea how can reload only updated view in the div?

To achieve your above requirement, as @Hopeless mentioned in comment, you can do some modifications to return a partial view result.

The following code works well for me, you can refer to it.

```
<form method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" ajax-data-records="records" data-ajax-update="#panel" data-ajax-mode='replace' data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("GetPartial","Home")">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">

        <select id="Records" name="records" class="form-control col-lg-12">

            <option value="0" selected>--Choose---</option>
            <option value="1">All Records</option>
            <option value="2">Per User</option>
        </select>

    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>

<div id="panel">

</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

}
```

*Action method*

```
public IActionResult GetPartial(int records)
{
    //code logic here
    //...

    //following code for testing purpose

    var model = new List<RequestModel>
    {
        new RequestModel
        {
            requestID = 1
        },
        new RequestModel
        {
            requestID = 2
        },
        new RequestModel
        {
            requestID = 3
        }
    };

    return PartialView("_MyPartial", model.Where(c => c.requestID > records).ToList());
}
```

*_MyPartial.cshtml file*

```
@model List<RequestModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_MyPartial";
}

@*<h1>_MyPartial</h1>*@

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.requestID<br />
}
```

*Model Class*

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int requestID { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]